# Unable to totally uninstall Oracle 11gR2 from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g

Mistakely i installed Oracle 11g enterprise edition like the steps of Express edition.That become failed.Then i try to install Oracle 11g Express edition.While installing on startup it is showing

```
**Selecting previously unselected package oracle-xe.
(Reading database ... 249055 files and directories currently installed.)**
```

i ran **ps -ef|grep mydb**

it is showing 
indrajit  3913  3881  0 09:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mydb

i tried all the possible way including dpkg --purge but the problem still there.Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  
I think that this question would be a better fit on http://askubuntu.com

Comment: 1) Remove the ORACLE_BASE folder 2) Rrmove /etc/oratab file 3)remove the file /etc/oraInst.loc  - Your Oracle DB is de-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you deinstalled Oracle 11gR2 enterprise edition using the standard procedure of running deinstall script.

```
> cd $ORACLE_HOME
> cd deinstall
```

List the files in the folder which will be similar to the following output.

```
> ls -ltr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle dba 32343 Dec 16 2009  sshUserSetup.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 409   Aug 18 2010  readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 3466  Aug 18 2010  deinstall.xml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle dba 9780  May 10 2011  bootstrap.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle dba 18475 Jun 9  2011  deinstall.pl
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle dba 4096  Feb 20 11:15 response
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle dba 4096  Feb 20 11:15 jlib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle dba 9655  Feb 20 11:17 deinstall

> ./deinstall
```

You need to run `deinstall` tool to remove oracle binaries.

Comment: yes i allready run deinstall tool.but the problem still exist

Comment: If deinstall is successful, then at least you got rid of Oracle 11gR2 enterprise edition.